# Architecture for energy savings application (.NET)

Tags: architecture, energy

I should do this task:

The microservice's mission is to estimate the Co2 saving for each intervention (it's energy field).

I need to multiply a fixed saving coefficient (equal to 600 Kg)
for the installations' number.

Once the microservice has been called,
it will return the total CO2 savings broken down by day, week, month, and year.

Can anyone give me an idea how to proceed?
(.NET field is fine).

Thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

Answer (score 1):

You can use prometheus to get standard metrics about process usage of your microservices over time. With these metrics you will be able to convert process consumption to an energy estimation.

Look this [repository](https://github.com/text-rl/environment) for an exemple of prometheus implementation for .Net 6 microservices.

After cloning this repository I suggest you to check submodule core-api-net, and docker examples.